# SLES15 SP4 | Does "wheel" group not exists anymore?

Tags: opensuse, sles

I have an old .spec file which I want to support for SLES15-SP4. The code tries to add a user in supplement group (`-G`) which is `wheel`. This line of code is not working for SLES15-SP4 and the `useradd` command results in error

```
group 'wheel' does not exist
```

My Questions are:

1. Is there any documentation for SLES15-SP4 where it is mentioned that wheel group is removed?
2. Can I add the user to  `root` group instead? I found this in SLES docs:

> By design, members of the group wheel can run all commands with sudo as root.

Comment: does `wheel` have any privileges other than being in `sudoers`? If that's all you want, add your user do /etc/sudoers like `yourusername ALL=(ALL)`, done.

Comment: @MarcusMüller uncommenting `wheel` group in /etc/sudoers not working for me. I logged out from machine and logged in again but still no effect. Any suggestions?

Comment: well, that's not what I suggested above. So, my suggestion is to read my first comment again.

Answer (score 0):

Run `zypper in system-group-wheel` to install the relevant package which creates this (optional) group.